# PHP Woocommerce Flatsome theme - Remove breadcrumb from shop page title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

1) I'm trying to remove the breacrumb from page-title div using php instead of display:none but i can't manage to found the good hook, i check in many different php files etc but anyway i'm not good enough in PHP. I'm like zero.

2) I also want to display the breadcrumb into the footer. I manage to found a way to add it into the footer already using simply

```
add_action( 'flatsome_footer', 'flatsome_breadcrumb', 10 );
```

But i did not found the hook to put it into their "footer-1" that is a child div of the footer block. This flatsome_footer is the parent div and it will make me add more css for it.

Here is the documentation of the flatsome theme (Actions & Filters), it may can help (i try many different as i say & open php files but cant manage to remove it by remove_action maybe i have to add filters idk... i'm just bad.

https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/385-hooks#flatsome_footer

All i know is that their page title block is using (shop-page-title category-page-title page-title) css class.

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove breadcrumb from shop or product page, you should findout hook from below files and comment that code.

**Category Page File**: yourthemepath/woocommerce/layouts/headers/category-title.php

Please check https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/385-hooks#flatsome_category_title

**Product Page:** https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/385-hooks#flatsome_product_title

Comment: Thx for quick anwser bro

Comment: I found this :

`<div class="flex-col medium-text-center">
<?php do_action('flatsome_category_title') ;?>`


Into the woocommerce/layouts/headers/category-title.php

So i try this :

`add_action('flatsome_category_title', 1);
    function remove_flatsome_category_title()
    {
  remove_action('flatsome_category_title', 10);

    }`

But it doesnt work the div class=flex-col medium-text-center is the good one used in the page so i guess it's this one :c

Comment: Remove breadcrumb hook from that file. Place this code remove_action('flatsome_category_title','flatsome_shop_loop_tools_breadcrumbs ',10);